# Laravel JSON Response for API Request Confusion

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a beginner at Laravel, just so you know. So I'm building an API for my site...

**I would like to know what is the difference between:**

- `response()->json($array, $status)` and
- `response($array, $status)`

because I have the following story:

---

From the official documentation, to give a JSON response, you use this:

```
response()->json($array, $status);
```

However, when I tried this code in my middleware to attempt to return a different response for API calls and HTTP requests:

<sub>**1st version**</sub>

```
    //I added this if block to my existing code.
    if ($request->wantsJson() || $request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json([
            "message" => "Unauthorized"
        ], 403);
    }
    return redirect('/home');
...
return $next($request);
```

It didn't work. It seems there is a problem with this code because Laravel refused to change its behavior. So the returned object was my homepage. Mind you I have the exact same "response structure"(i.e. `response()->json($array, $status)`) in my Controller in which I have added this middleware, and that response worked!

---

Then I also found this in the documentation:

```
response($content, $status)
```

So when I tried this:

<sub>**2nd version**</sub>

```
    return response("unauthorized", 403);
    if ($request->wantsJson() || $request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json([
            "message" => "Unauthorized"
        ], 403);
    }
    return redirect('/home');
...
return $next($request);
```

It worked as expected and returned the string. But when I changed back to my 1st version, the behavior of this version stuck. So it kept returning this string.

---

So I tried this:

<sub>**3rd version**</sub>

```
    if ($request->wantsJson() || $request->ajax()) {
        return response([
            "message" => "Unauthorized"
        ], 403);
    }
    return redirect('/home');
...
return $next($request);
```

And it worked and returned a JSON document.

Why is that so? Why didn't `response()->json($array, $status)` work in my middleware but worked in my controller? And what are the differences between the two ways of writing a response, because according to Postman, both replies has the same headers and correctly presented themselves as JSON documents.

Comment: `$request->wantsJson() || $request->ajax()` was false when you tested your first two versions.

Comment: @sisve I don't think so :/ I tinkered around with the code, even removing the conditions, but the response was still problematic. Even when I removed the redirect line, the code still returned my entire homepage.

Comment: @sisve There was no recorded errors either, I checked the log.